# Element won't work in fixed display, but works in relative display

Tags: html, css

For ".header-links a", I am trying to make the links a fixed display, but when the position is fixed, it messes up the layout. It won't mess up the layout when the position is relative, but that's not what I want. I want the links to be fixed.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  color: #3d3d5c;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 17.9rem;
}

.header-links a {
  color: #cccfc2;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <hr>
  <header>
    <nav class="header-links">
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element to be set fixed should be `.header-links` instead of its child.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 500rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 18rem;
}

hr {
  color: #3d3d5c;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 6rem;
  width: 17.9rem;
}

.header-links {
  position: fixed; /* add this and you may also set its position */
}
.header-links a {
  color: #cccfc2;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  top: 9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <hr>
  <header>
    <nav class="header-links">
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
      <a href="#About">About</a>
      <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```